# Selectively read part of JSON data using JsonSerializer and populate a c# object

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I connect to a 3rd party webservice that returns a complex JSON object that only contains a few bits of information I actually need.

Basically, I just need the array in "value". From that array, I just need the "Id", "Title" and "Status" properties.

I want to put those attributes into a c# class called Project. This is my class:

```
public class Project
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Status { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to use this code to read the JSON and do the transform:

```
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
        returnValue = serializer.Deserialize<Project>(jsonTextReader);
    }
}
```

Example JSON:

```
{
    "odata.metadata":"http://school.edu/Api/1/$metadata#Projects",
    "odata.count":"3",
    "value":[
        {
            "odata.id":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('123')",
            "RelatedProjects@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('123')/RelatedProjects",
            "Tags@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('123')/Tags",
            "TimedEvents@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('123')/Categories",
            "ep@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('123')/ep",
            "#CreateLike":{
                    "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('123')/CreateLike"
                  },
            "#CreateShortcut":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('123')/CreateShortcut"
                      },
            "#Play":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Play/123"
                      },
            "#SendInvitation":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('123')/SendInvitation"
                      },
            "#CopyProject":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('123')/CopyProject"
                      },
            "#AddVideoPodcast":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('123')/AddVideoPodcast"
                      },
            "#AddEP":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('123')/AddEP"
                      },
            "Id":"123",
            "Title":"Test Title 1",
            "Status":"Viewable"
        },
        {
            "odata.id":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('456')",
            "RelatedProjects@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('456')/RelatedProjects",
            "Tags@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('456')/Tags",
            "TimedEvents@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('456')/Categories",
            "ep@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('456')/ep",
            "#CreateLike":{
                    "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('456')/CreateLike"
                  },
            "#CreateShortcut":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('456')/CreateShortcut"
                      },
            "#Play":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Play/456"
                      },
            "#SendInvitation":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('456')/SendInvitation"
                      },
            "#CopyProject":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('456')/CopyProject"
                      },
            "#AddVideoPodcast":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('456')/AddVideoPodcast"
                      },
            "#AddEP":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('456')/AddEP"
                      },
            "Id":"456",
            "Title":"Test Title 2",
            "Status":"Viewable"
        },
        {
            "odata.id":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('789')",
            "RelatedProjects@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('789')/RelatedProjects",
            "Tags@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('789')/Tags",
            "TimedEvents@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('789')/Categories",
            "ep@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('789')/ep",
            "#CreateLike":{
                    "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('789')/CreateLike"
                  },
            "#CreateShortcut":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('789')/CreateShortcut"
                      },
            "#Play":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Play/789"
                      },
            "#SendInvitation":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('789')/SendInvitation"
                      },
            "#CopyProject":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('789')/CopyProject"
                      },
            "#AddVideoPodcast":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('789')/AddVideoPodcast"
                      },
            "#AddEP":{
                        "target":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Projects('789')/AddEP"
                      },
            "Id":"789",
            "Title":"Test Title 3",
            "Status":"Viewable"
        }
  ],
  "odata.nextLink":"http://school.edu/Api/1/Folders('xyz')/Projects?$skip=10&$top=10"
}
```

I just get a null object back. But in the debugger, I can see that it's pulling all the JSON data from the webservice.

How can I get what I need from the JSON, build my c# objects, and ignore all the rest?

Comment: Having looked at the Deserialize documentation there doesn't appear to be inherent functionality for this.  Therefore for the sake of spending time waiting for an answer can you not deserialize the whole thing, then selectively use the properties you need?

Comment: @m.edmondson thanks.  Stupid question, but without deserializing, how would I get at the data/attributes I need?

Comment: Are you not able to deserialize the whole response?

Comment: I can see it in my debugger when I do something like this: var rawJson = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(); That gives me a giant string of JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use `Json.NET` (Newtonsoft json), you can utilize `Linq-to-Json` like this [1]

```
//using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:YourDirectory\file.json"); //source
var projects = new List<Project>(); //Your result

JObject data = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
foreach (var value in data["value"])
{
    projects.Add(new Project
    {
        Id = value["Id"].ToString(),
        Status = value["Status"].ToString(),
        Title = value["Title"].ToString()
    });
}
```

Or, you can also deserialize the `JObject` like this [2]

```
var jsonReader = data["value"].CreateReader();
projects = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<List<Project>>(jsonReader);
```

Both works just fine, but which one is better?

The second approach means less code (specially, if you have many properties in `Project` class, you'll have to write many lines of code to map each properties in code [1]).

But the performance of the first approach is many times better! For the given json data, code [1] runs roughly in **1 ms** while code [2] takes more than **100 ms**!

---

**Update**

After input from *James Newton-King (who wrote Json.NET :)* , there is another even more elegant way of doing this [3]

```
projects = data["value"].ToObject<List<Project>>();
```

And guess what! This code [3] takes nearly **half** the time of approach [1]. So, from all perspectives, this has to be the best approach!

Comment: Your second example can be improved: data["value"].ToObject<List<Project>>()

Comment: @JamesNewton-King Ah! I didn't know that, thanks. I have updated my answer to include that, and it also shows the best performance as per my stopwatch test :)